# Printing Point array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, point

I been stuck on this for a while now. I have read an Object which is a `Point` type and I want to assign it to a `Point` array and print it. For some reason my code isnt printing anything..would anyone know what is causing this.

```
private Point[] pointArray;
while ((obj = inStream.readObject()) != null)

            {

                Point pointValue = (Point) obj;

                int xValue = pointValue.x;
                int yValue = pointValue.y;

                pointArray[counter] = new Point(xValue, yValue);

                System.out.println(pointArray[counter].toString());
                counter++;
            }
```

Comment: The array is declared but not initialized.

Comment: What is exception here.Can we have log here for better understand

Comment: I dont know the size of the array as it depends on the file.

Comment: then use an ArrayList<Point> ?

Comment: It works with ArrayList but I want to use an array

Answer (score 2):

You could use an ArrayList to read the points, then convert it to your array:

```
    List<Point> points = new ArrayList();

    // Read Points and add them to the list
    // points.add(new Point(1, 2));
    // points.add(new Point(3, 4));

    Point[] pointsArray = new Point[points.size()];
    points.toArray(pointsArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have a fixed size in Java, you'll need to use an ArrayList so something like:

```
    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    while ((obj = inStream.readObject()) != null) {

        Point pointValue = (Point) obj;

        int xValue = pointValue.x;
        int yValue = pointValue.y;

        points.add(new Point(xValue, yValue));

        System.out.println(points.get(points.size()-1).toString());
        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that it works with Arraylist already.

Answer (score 1):

Before run your code you need to correct your code else this code not compile at least.

```
private Point[] pointArray; // you have declare the array
```

But you never initialize it. First initialize this.

Again you are calling `toString()` method of an `Array`. Never do that since it will call `Object` class `toString()` method in `Java`.

Edit: for your comment.

```
I dont know the size of the array as it depends on the file.
```

Then use `List` instead of `Array`

```
List<Point> pointsList=new ArrayList<>();
```

Not only this advantage but also you can directly call `toString()` not like in `Arrays`. Since toString() method has `override` in `AbstractCollection`, you need to override `toString()` method in your `Point` class

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the above code that the array is not initialized and according to you you don't have the actual size to initialize it so you can go with list the convert the list to array if you neeed

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    while ((obj = inStream.readObject()) != null) {

        Point pointValue = (Point) obj;

        int xValue = pointValue.x;
        int yValue = pointValue.y;

        pointsList.add(new Point(xValue, yValue));

        System.out.println(pointsList.get(pointsList.size()-1).toString());
        counter++;
    }
    Point[] pointsArray = pointsList.toArray(new Point[pointsList.size()]);
```